# Can't find Use Nodes in Light settings?

Tags: light, lighting

Just started blender, following the donut tutorial. Using Blender 2.8. made another donut to practice, when adding Lights I can't find the 'Use Nodes' in the Light settings. Some help would be appreciated <3
[image]

Comment: What happens if you go into the node editor? I think it might just already be checked by default, so they removed the button, but you should still be fine without it.

Comment: Doesn't show any nodes and I can't add any to the Light either. I can edit normally in the Node editor only for "World" but not the Light

Comment: You'll need to set the correct render engine. In file 2 very likely you have set it to eevee. Use cycles instead.

Comment: Ahhhh!!! Thanks that worked! Thanks for the quick replies yall <3 Off I go making more donuts :D

Answer (score 10):

You need to be in Cycles to be able to see the *Use Nodes* button for lights